# Remove dataTable Class from datatable

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatable

Is it possible to remove `class="dataTable"` from datatable and apply our own class. If so, then how to do it ?
I tried Jquery something like this.

```
  $('#sourceDetails').removeClass('dataTable');
```

But no effect.

Comment: Can you share the html??

Comment: <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" id="someid" class="display dataTable" aria-describedby="someid_info"> html is generated dynamically. But i am posting just the table tag for your reference

Comment: And when you want to do removing of class and adding anotehr??

Comment: I just removed the class from my dataTable using the JQuery you tried in the question. Worked for me O_O Why didn't it work for you?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
$('#sourceDetails').addClass("NewClassName").removeClass('dataTable');
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('table').removeClass('dataTable');
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
 $('#someid').addClass('newclass').removeClass('dataTable');
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
$(function () {
    setTimeout(function () {
        $('#sourceDetails').removeClass('dataTable');
    }, 100);
});
```